# module + routing + component in angular

Tags: angular, module, command

I try to create module + routing + component in angular
I added the following command
ng g m general-parameter --routing --route general-parameter --module=pages.module
but it get error
"Specified module 'pages.module' does not exist.
Looked in the following directories:
/src/app/pages/general-parameter
/src/app/pages/pages.module
/src/app/pages
src/app/pages
/src/app
/src
"
What is the problem??
Thank you

I added the following command
ng g m general-parameter --routing --route general-parameter --module=pages.module
but it get error
"Specified module 'pages.module' does not exist.
Looked in the following directories:
/src/app/pages/general-parameter
/src/app/pages/pages.module
/src/app/pages
src/app/pages
/src/app
/src
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following commands:

```
ng g m generalParameter --routing=true
```

- `ng g m generalParameter` will create your module
- `--routing=true` will create it as a routing module

```
ng g c generalParameter --skip-tests=true -m=generalParameter
```

- `ng g c generalParameter` will create your component
- `--skip-tests=true` will skip generating the test file
- `-m=generalParameter` will place your component under the specified module and automatically generate declarations under the module

You can also run them in a single command by combining them like this:

```
ng g m generalParameter --routing=true && ng g c generalParameter --skip-tests=true -m=generalParameter
```

Hope this helps.